# Can I access a SharePoint List or library with an InDesign HTML file?

Tags: 2010, list, data

I'm looking to Use InDesign to create an interactive object that creates "click and reveals" that reveal data from SharePoint data. How would this task be done?

Answer (score 1):

Im just confused why you would use InDesign?

to show and hide lists you can either do it by a feature or webpart or aps.net page and have jquery/javascript that attach to the button or better yet use AjaxControlToolkit.dll to do the job for updatepanel, up/down panel popup or not, show/hide list and it goes on and on.

If you want you can design it in sharepoint designer, change the css and more!

So I dont see why you want to use html when you have somthing 100000000% more powerfull to use ;)

hope this answers your question.

**EDIT**

ahh ok that explains alot! i would go with JQuery, you can place the Jquery file to the page, within the JQuery you can than show hide with animation which is easy aslong as you have unique controls to click on show and hide... i dont know the html that is produced so cant give you code example but as for the JQuery example:

http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

html

```
<div id="clickme">  Click here</div><img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123">
```

JQ

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {  $( "#book" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {    // Animation complete.  });});
```

Comment: Let me elaborate on my reasoning.  I am trying to connect information to a dynamic infographic.  I have the infographic in InDesign, but I'm looking for click and reveals to work in the HTML file that InDesign produces.

Comment: just ammended my answer